# How can I add condition in class on vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My component vue is like this :

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block" :class="{ product == 'responseFound' ? ' btn-default' : ' btn-success' }" @click="add($event)">
        ...
</template>
```

There exist error :

> invalid expression: :class="{ product == 'responseFound' ? '
>   btn-default' : ' btn-success' }"

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the brackets in `:class`:

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block" :class="product == 'responseFound' ? ' btn-default' : ' btn-success'" @click="add($event)">
        ...
</template>
```

If you want to add more conditions, wrap it with `[]` to create an array:

```
:class="[product == 'responseFound' ? ' btn-default' : ' btn-success', foo ? 'foo' : 'bar']"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a computed property for this kind of behaviour.

Which removes the logic from your template, and moves it into your script part.

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block" :class="classes" @click="add($event)">
</template>

    <script>
      export default {
         computed: {
                classes() {
                    return this.product == 'responseFound' ? 'btn-default' : 'btn-success'             
                }
            }
         }
    </script>
```